# Send data to iPhone App without waking it up

Tags: ios, ios4, core-location

I have a requirement where I need to send some data from my server to the client (app on iphone) and then the app will use "Significant-Change Location Service" to create some alerts based on the user's location. I would like to do all of these even if the app has been terminated. At the same time I don't want to wake up the app when I am doing this.

The only time app should wake up is when the user reaches to a location that has been set by the app, apart from when user himself opens the app.

I was looking at the Push notification but that will wake up the app, which I don't want.

Thanks,
Yogesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `UILocalNotification` to send a local notification in the case where you want to inform the user. There's some [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/iphone/library/samplecode/LocationReminders/Introduction/Intro.html) that was demoed at WWDC 2010 that does exactly that. Not sure if the link works for non-attendees, though.

Comment: the problem her is without telling the user i want to wake the app from the server, not locally.

Comment: For each location update, you can ask the server (while running in the background) whether to show a notification or not and its content.